# Does Python have a default Caching service

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, caching, local-storage

Similar to `redis` and `memcache`, does Python by default has a caching attached to its run time environment?

This has to be local caching.
I need to know without installing or invoking any other libraries, can I cache some data using the existing Python installation in my system.
I need to add data to a `dict` , but before that if there is any default cache, I need to add to that.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: A cache is simply something stored in memory. Storing data in a python `dict` could be considered a cache, so you need to be more specific.

Comment: Python dict should work for you. But I guess you are looking for something like Python equivalent of Guava cache https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained or  expiring map http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/ExpiringMap.htm . Similar stuffs can be easily implemented in Python (backed by Python dict).

Comment: Python 3 has [`lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) that wraps around functions, build args to result dictionary and when function is called with the same  arguments, it will use dict instead of calling function itself.

Comment: Thank you all !! 
lru_cache would help me

Comment: [shelve](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/shelve.html?highlight=shelve) can cache data on disk; but is not as comfortable as `lru_cache` if you want to meomize a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you need to do. If you give a function a default argument that equates to a list or dictionary and never give it an argument for that default, the function parameter could act as a cache. The reason for this is because Python evaluates its function definition at compile time, so the function argument will be loaded in at compile time. Take for example this code:

```
def foo(value, arr=[]):
    arr.append(value)
    return arr
```

When ran like so:

```
for i in range(10):
    foo(i)
```

the result is:

```
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```